# Est-ce qu'il y a un enchaînement dans cet exemple ?

Tags: phonétique

Dans *ils s'aiment* /il.sɛm/ le "s" du mot "se" appartient à la deuxième syllabe, alors est-ce que c'est considéré comme un enchaînement ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non, Il s'agit ici d'une **élision**

Citation de l'article [wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89lision?wprov=sfla1) :

> L’élision n’est en effet représentée graphiquement que pour certains mots, parmi lesquels :
>    - le : le + arbre → l’arbre ; 
>    - de : de + arbre → d’arbre ;
>    - ce (pronom) : ce + était → c’était.

Et voici en plus un [article de blog](http://mamiehiou.over-blog.com/article-la-liaison-l-elision-l-enchainement-la-disjonction-97152248.html) qui parle de la différence entre liaison, élision et enchaînement.

Comment: Merci beaucoup !